# using group semi direct product to show an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

> If the groups $H \unlhd G; \  \ K \unlhd G; \  \ G=HK $ prove :
>   $$\frac{G}{H \cap K} \cong \frac{G}{H} \times \frac{G}{K}$$

So if $\varphi : G \to \frac{G}{H} \times \frac{G}{K}$ is surjective then $Im(\varphi) = \frac{G}{H} \times \frac{G}{K} $
 and $ ker(\varphi) = {H \cap K} $  then that is sufficient proof for the 1st isomorphism theorem.
I take $(g_1, g_2)\in  \frac{G}{H} \times \frac{G}{K} \ s.t. \varphi(g) = (g_1H, g_2K) = (gH,gK) $  and find the appropriate $g$
$g_1 = h_1k_1 \ ; g_2=h_2k_2 $ since $G=HK$  this is where I'm stuck, $g=g_1=g_2$ but why is that true for arbitrary $g_1 , g_2$?
edit:
if $g_1=h_1k_1$ then $g_1H = k_1H ; \ g_2K= h_2K ; \ g=k_1=h_2 $? I think that's a contradiction because $H \cap K$ should be $\{e\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. Given $g_1,g_2 \in G$, write $g_1=h_1k_1$, $g_2=h_2k_2$. Then $\phi(h_2k_1) = (g_1H,g_2K)$, so $\phi$ is surjective.